# How to deploy Serverless Framework to AWS from Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, serverless-framework

I'm wanting to get familiar with Azure DevOps and setting up CI/CD through it.  For the backend services, I want to use Serverless Framework (SF).  I'm getting stuck trying to add credentials to the CI pipeline for SF.

I'm following the instructions in [this documentation page](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/guides/cicd/running-in-your-own-cicd) but I'm getting this error in the deploy step.

> AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here:

These are the steps to reproduce:

- Create a SF service, initial a git repo and add it to the Azure project.

```
sls create -t aws-nodejs-typescript -p api-hello-service
cd api-hello-service
git init
git add .
git commit -m 'initial commit'
git remote add origin <origin>
```

- In the Serverless Framework Dashboard, go to org and create an access key (save the key for later)
  [image]
- In the Azure DevOps GUI, refresh the Repo page and click the "Setup Build" button
  [image]
- Select the Node.js template as a base.
  [image]
- Customize the pipeline

```
# azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm install -g serverless
    serverless deploy
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

- Set the variable `SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY` as described in the documentation earlier with the access key create in SF Dashboard earlier. (check "Keep this value secret")
- Hit save & run

Deploy step fails:

```
Starting: npm install and build
==============================================================================
Task         : Command line
Description  : Run a command line script using Bash on Linux and macOS and cmd.exe on Windows
Version      : 2.201.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/dec6f028-dba1-4c47-8718-cb65524f31a1.sh
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please downgrade to v7.1.5 if you need IE/ActiveXObject support OR upgrade to v8.0.0 as we no longer support IE and published an incorrect patch version (see https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1731)
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.

added 474 packages, and audited 475 packages in 16s

88 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated superagent@7.1.6: Please downgrade to v7.1.5 if you need IE/ActiveXObject support OR upgrade to v8.0.0 as we no longer support IE and published an incorrect patch version (see https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent/issues/1731)

added 425 packages, and audited 426 packages in 6s

87 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
Running "serverless" from node_modules

Deploying api-hello-service to stage dev (us-east-1)

× Stack api-hello-service-dev failed to deploy (0s)
Environment: linux, node 16.17.0, framework 3.22.0 (local) 3.22.0v (global), plugin 6.2.2, SDK 4.3.2
Docs:        docs.serverless.com
Support:     forum.serverless.com
Bugs:        github.com/serverless/serverless/issues

Error:
AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here: <http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup>.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: npm install and build
```

---

Update:

Default generated serverless.ts

```js
import type { AWS } from '@serverless/typescript';

import hello from '@functions/hello';

const serverlessConfiguration: AWS = {
  service: 'api-hello-service',
  frameworkVersion: '3',
  plugins: ['serverless-esbuild'],
  provider: {
    name: 'aws',
    runtime: 'nodejs14.x',
    apiGateway: {
      minimumCompressionSize: 1024,
      shouldStartNameWithService: true,
    },
    environment: {
      AWS_NODEJS_CONNECTION_REUSE_ENABLED: '1',
      NODE_OPTIONS: '--enable-source-maps --stack-trace-limit=1000',
    },
  },
  // import the function via paths
  functions: { hello },
  package: { individually: true },
  custom: {
    esbuild: {
      bundle: true,
      minify: false,
      sourcemap: true,
      exclude: ['aws-sdk'],
      target: 'node14',
      define: { 'require.resolve': undefined },
      platform: 'node',
      concurrency: 10,
    },
  },
};

module.exports = serverlessConfiguration;
```

---

Update: 2

Looks like I was missing `app` & `org` in my serverless config.

Now I'm receiving `Error: You are not currently logged in. To log in, use: $ serverless login`.

Am I setting the API key incorrectly?

[image: azure pipeline]

Comment: Hey there, could you share your `serverless.yml` file with sensitive parts masked out? Did you set `app` and `org` in your configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use credentials configured as a part of Serverless Dashboard, you need to set corresponding `app` and `org` in your configuration, and then expose `SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY` as env var in case of CI/CD setup. So, in your case, adding configured `org` and `app` to config should resolve the problem.

Comment: Getting a new error now: `Error:
You are not currently logged in. To log in, use: $ serverless login`

Comment: Hey @Dan - are you sure you've set the `SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY` env var in CI? It's the equivalent of being logged in

Comment: Not sure actually... new to Azure.  Update 2 in the OP shows what I see.  That look correct?

Comment: Hey @Dan - unfortunately, I'm not familiar with Azure Pipelines at all, but it seems like maybe the env var is not set after all. You might try to debug it by just trying to echo first few chars of that env var before invoking `serverless`

Comment: Azure masks secret variables.  I ended up adding `export SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY=$env:SERVERLESS_ACCESS_KEY ` before the deploy line.  Ended up getting another error: `Error: Authentication failed. - Please contact support and provide this identifier to reference this issue - HXXXXXXX`.  Ended up just switching to Github and with this [template](https://github.com/serverless/github-action) it worked the first time no issue, so I'm probably going to give up on Azure.